# SendGrid and Arm Template

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-rm-template, sendgrid-templates

I have added Send Grid API Key into App Settings as follows:

[image]

I have an ARM Template with resources element which includes the following:

```
"resources": [               
    {
       "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "name": "appsettings",
        "type": "config",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('apiApp').name)]"
        ],
        "properties": {
           "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId(variables('dataResourceGroup').name, 'Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('dataAppInsights').name), '2014-04-01').InstrumentationKey]",
           "apiClientId": "[parameters('apiAppId')]",
           "prereqsKeyVaultName": "[concat(parameters('solutionAbbreviation'), '-prereqs-', parameters('environmentAbbreviation'))]",
           "dataKeyVaultName": "[concat(parameters('solutionAbbreviation'), '-data-', parameters('environmentAbbreviation'))]"
         }
     }
]
```

How do I add SENDGRID_APIKEY into ARM Template and use that in the program shown below?

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        Execute().Wait();
    }
    static async Task Execute()
    {
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("abc.com", "ABC");
        var subject = "Testing SendGrid";
        var to = new EmailAddress("xyz.com", "XYZ"); 
        var plainTextContent = "This is a test";
        var htmlContent = "test";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand the question, just add it as another key\value pair?

```
"resources": [               
    {
       "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "name": "appsettings",
        "type": "config",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('apiApp').name)]"
        ],
        "properties": {
           "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId(variables('dataResourceGroup').name, 'Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('dataAppInsights').name), '2014-04-01').InstrumentationKey]",
           "apiClientId": "[parameters('apiAppId')]",
           "prereqsKeyVaultName": "[concat(parameters('solutionAbbreviation'), '-prereqs-', parameters('environmentAbbreviation'))]",
           "dataKeyVaultName": "[concat(parameters('solutionAbbreviation'), '-data-', parameters('environmentAbbreviation'))]",
           "SENDGRIP_APIKEY": "somevalue"
         }
     }
]
```

if you want to dynamically pass it, add another parameter and reference that parameter like you do any other `[parameters('sendgrid')]`

Comment: Thanks! Where do I get SendGrid Account Name from?

Comment: I have no idea about sendgrid, probably somewhere on their site

Comment: @user3693060 you need to register through Azure marketplace for sendgrid for a free account or paid account to get the API key